# Porque meu icon n troca de cor msm usando o "color" no css o icon esta sendo usado como botao

Tags: html, css

html

```
            <div id="center-text">
                <a href="inicio.html" target="_blank">
                    <i class="fa-solid fa-house"></i>
                </a>
            </div>
```

e no css

```
#center-text {
    position: fixed;
    width: 10px;
    bottom: 40px;
    color: #fff;
}
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Nesse caso o seu código não está funcionando da forma que você gostaria por que você selecionou o id da div ou invés de selecionar a class do seu icon. O que eu fiz abaixo foi apenas selecionar a class do seu icon e adicionar uma cor a ele.

```html
            <div id="center-text">
                <a href="inicio.html" target="_blank">
                    <i class="fa-solid fa-house"></i>
                </a>
            </div>
```

```css
#center-text {
    position: fixed;
    width: 10px;
    bottom: 40px;
}

.fa-house{
    color:#fff;
}
```

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).